# Activating concrete button type="submit" JavaScript or JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

I have a Form 
In it, select the button  
So I choose to select a value, push the Change button and following me everything works as it should.
code

```
<form method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" enctype="multipart/form-data">

    <select class="hl-1a sel" id="select1" name="select1" >
        <option value="1" > 1 </option>
        <option value="2" > 2 </option>
        <option value="3" > 3 </option>
        <input type="submit" id="100" name ="100" value="ZMEN" /> 
    </select>

    <br />
    <br />
    <input type="submit" name="odoslat" value="ODOSLAŤ" /> 

</form>
```

But we need to select me respond without pressing ZMEN, so I added a select onchange='this.form.submit()' 
I need to get my `onchange` activate button

```
<input type="submit" id="100" name ="100" value="ZMEN" />
```

and not the main button Form

```
<input type="submit" name="odoslat" value="ODOSLAŤ" />
```

code after adding `onchange='this.form.submit()'`

```
<form method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" enctype="multipart/form-data">

    <select class="hl-1a sel" id="select1" name="select1" onchange='this.form.submit()' > <!--  Here I added the onchange  -->
        <option value="1" > 1 </option>
        <option value="2" > 2 </option>
        <option value="3" > 3 </option>
        <input type="submit" id="100" name ="100" value="ZMEN" /> <!--  I need to get my onchange activate this button  -->
    </select>

    <br />
    <br />
    <input type="submit" name="odoslat" value="ODOSLAT" /> <!-- onchange me this button activates which for me is inconvenient -->

</form>
```

But in this case I `onchange = 'this.form.submit ()'` button activates the main form `ODOSLAT`, which is inconvenient for me.

**As could be achieved JavaScript to be activated after I change the value of a SELECT button automatically ZMEN.**

```
<input type="submit" id="100" name ="100" value="ZMEN" />
```

Could someone please advise. Thank you in advance.

Comment: An INPUT cannot be child of a SELECT

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to move your submit button outside of the `<select>` element. Then you'll want to click on the correct submit button when the select elements value changes. Using jQuery that would look like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#select1').on('change', function(e) {$('#100').click();});
});
```

Comment: Anthony Grist veľmi pekne vám ďakujem. oto je presne to, čo potrebujem. Pri select to funguje na 100%